# Display a "visible-lg" div in mobile via jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

this question can sound strange for the fact that if I define a div with "visible-lg" attribute on bootstrap, I'm doing this to show only on desktop devices. But I want some kind of behavior for responsive layout using this classes.

What I want to achieve is: I have 3 columns (col-lg-2, col-lg-3 and col-lg-7) the 2 last columns (lg-3 and lg-7) both have the "visible-lg" property, this way on mobile I see only the first. What I want to achieve is: when I click in some button (that will be visible only for mobiles with "visible-xs" on the first col), I do something like:

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    $(".col1").slideUp(); //hide the first col
    $(".col2").slideDown(); //show the second (with visible-lg)
});
```

Why I want this? Let's suppose when the user clicks on this button, I populate the second column with something specific for the button he hit on the first, and I want to show the second column now with the contents. But I want to show only one column per time on mobile devices, making this responsive.

Is possible to do this using the responsive utilities of bootstrap + jQuery or I'll need to write a new CSS class?

Comment: [Per the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes), `visible-lg`, `visible-xs`, etc are **deprecated as of v3.2.0**. You should use their counterparts that describe *how* they should be visible (e.g. `visible-lg-inline` or `visible-xs-block`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still not sure if this will work as I want (with full details, etc...), but to show the div that previously was hidden on mobile, instead of using:

> $(".col2").slideDown();

I used:

> $(".col2").toggleClass("visible-xs");

This way I added the class 'visible-xs' and it became visible on mobile too.